Create a tag <meta .../>
When I do:

const meta = document.createElement("meta");

document.head.appendChild( meta );

It creates a tag <meta>
I want to know how to create one tag <meta/> auto-closed at the end without another tag to close.
I can pass one string on anyTag.innerHTML="<meta/>" but I don't want to do this.
I want to know how to create an autoclosed tag.
I try reading the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement.

There is absolutely no point to doing that.

Also self-closure is an XML thing, and HTML parsers completely ignore it.

Reference for @Pointy's comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element#self-closing_tags

Why do you think you need to do this?  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

@Pointy, the point is: The google Schollar need this tag in this exact way to confirm that site is mine. And the only one way to me to put this tag on my site is by javascript. So, I need to create a tag in this exact way. you can confirm this on https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome

@David, I need this becouse https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome need to confirm my site. So i need to pub this exact tag <meta ... /> on my site... and MORE the only way that i can do it is by javascript so I need to learn how to do this with javascript.

A tag, once parsed and made part of the DOM, does not haven an <, it does not have a >, it does not have any of that stuff. It is a data structure that's part of the overall document; it's not text. HTML is parsed and turned into the DOM, and once that happens, the HTML syntax is not relevant any longer.

Can't really see how the "welcome" link provided is relevant.  If it's a third-party loading your site, then they'll very likely be reading the source HTML - not the DOM.   It's possibly it will apply js, but highly unlikely.    So even if you could get it to work, it probably won't work for that site.

document.createElement("meta") does not create a <meta> tag in the HTML code, it creates a meta element in the DOM.
Even your workaround with .innerHTML="<meta/>" would not create a "self-closing" element, it would just be parsed into a DOM element, the same way as .innerHTML="<meta></meta>".
If you need some specific HTML syntax, then you need to edit the HTML code somehow, i.e. the actual file that contains the HTML code.
HTML vs DOM
HTML has start-tags and end-tags and "self-closing" tags. These tags form HTML elements (e.g. <span>...</span> is a span element, described by a <span> start-tag and a </span> end-tag).
The browser parses the HTML code, and creates DOM nodes from it.
DOM nodes don't have tags. There is no "start" or "end" of a DOM node, it's just a DOM element (e.g. span).
Javascript can only create DOM nodes, therefore it is not possible to explicitly create a "self-closing" element, as the concept of "closing" a DOM element doesn't exist.
